# How to set custom Terms and Conditions in a php facebook application?

Tags: php

I am developing a facebook PHP application. I want to set my own terms and conditions in the facebook *allow page* (the page in which the app requests user permission to allow that app).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Go here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/##ID_YOUR_APP##/auth